# Solaris Milliseconds to Date

Tags: bash, solaris-10

I am using  Sun OS 5.10
and Using nawk to extract field from csv file.
The first column of csv is the time in Milliseconds and I need to convert it to Date then save it in another csv file.

Here is the command that handle this task

```
nawk 'BEGIN {FS = ","}; NR>1 split($42,a,"|") {print $1 "," $46 "," $48 "," 
$47 "," null "," null "," a[2] "," $6 "," $49 "," $7 "," $8 ","}' ttt.csv  > 
tttn.csv
```

How can I handle this task?

Comment: What's the question? You have the command that does it. Or doesn't the command work? If not, please identify the problem.

Comment: the question is the first column is Milliseconds like this 1521805499.928267630 and i need to convert it to Date like this 3/23/2018, 1:44:59 PM

Comment: I can't see a CSV file.

Comment: ISO8601 makes sense for dates https://xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 0):

Those are not milliseconds - they are seconds since the epoch on 1st Jan 1970.

Does this help? I change the value of the first field (`$1`) then print the line with the modified field:

```
awk '{$1=strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %r",int($1))}1' YourFile
03/26/2018, 07:04:47 pm field2 field3
```

where `YourFile` contains:

```
1522087487.9876 field2 field3
```

If you want rounding to the nearest second, you may want:

```
int($1+0.5)
```

in the `strftime()` function.

If your `nawk` doesn't have `strftime()`, and none of the other `awk`s on Solaris work, e.g. `/usr/xpg4/awk` etc, then we may have to come up with a Perl solution - just say!